# How to filter based on properties of lazy load entities

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql

I have a table Member which as a lazy load entity User.

```
Member   User
------   ----
id       id
User     name 

DetachedCriteria dc = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Member.class, "m");
dc.setFetchMode("user",FetchMode.JOIN);
dc.add(Restrictions.like("user.name", "alpha", MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
Criteria criteria = dc.getExecutableCriteria(session.getSession());
List<Membership> list = criteria.list();
```

It throws hibernate exception cannot resolve property user.name in member table.

How to use restricitions of properties from a lazy load associated entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an alias to access the properties of user. Change to the following for this to work :

```
DetachedCriteria dc = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Member.class, "m");
dc.createAlias("user", "u");
dc.add(Restrictions.like("u.name", "alpha", MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
Criteria criteria = dc.getExecutableCriteria(session.getSession());
List<Membership> list = criteria.list();
```